# local storage setting initial data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using backbone.js, I have preexisting data on a .json file, that I want to use as a setup for whenever a user starts the app, so that it stores into the local storage, then isnt used again.

**Example:** I run an each on my collection, then create each attribute like below, this set's the data inside the local storage then I comment out the json url, and just get data from local storage at this point.

```
_.each(this.players, function(player) {

    playersCollection.create({
      name: player.get('name'),
      team: player.get('team'),
      team_id: player.get('team_id'),
      number: player.get('number'),
      points: player.get('points')  
    })

}, this);
```

So is there a good way to do this, maybe even like a button that says populate app (behind the scenes its just storing the data on local storage from the url method then closing the url method), is this a good/bad idea?

I would like to know the best way to have this existing data, from the .json url ran on the app set into local storage then work directly with local storage for `CRUD` operations.

**Here is my backbone collection**

```
// Players Collection
// ---------------

// The collection of players is backed by *localStorage* instead of a remote
// server.
window.PlayersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Player,
        //url: data/players.json 
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("players-backbone"),
});

// Create our global collection of **playersCollection**.
window.playersCollection = new PlayersCollection;
```

Basically what I hope to achieve from this question is what's the best way to populate local storage data, because most tutorials talk about starting from scratch, you know say a user management system or to-do list, initially there is no data, the user creates the data to be stored into the local storage. Well I have data that is important to make my app function.

**Edit:** Let me just add, say that if I delete all the data from local storage, to re-populate it I have to comment out the `playersCollection.fetch` then hard code the json data into my collection, then run the code I posted above, in order to populate my local storage. At this point then I can edit the data, and play with the app nicely.

Is there a way to say if local storage with an id of "myid" is empty then use the "preexisting" data then render that code I wrote above to `create` and populate local storage, else if it contains data with "myid" then leave alone?

Comment: Does this make sense do I need to cover anything?

Comment: I am still open to other answers. I need a little better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would fetch the initial data explicitly using `$.ajax()` and then rely on an extension such as [backbone-localstorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to manage it.

More specifically:

```
$.ajax('path/to/data.json')
    .done(function(data) {
        coll = new Coll(data);
    );
```

Add error handling and options to taste

Comment: Okay ajax, sounds like Ill need to figure out how to implement that, I use ajax in regular jQuery, never in backbone.js... could you provide a little snippet/example or some links.. in what you're saying, I could use ajax to fetch data from a local .json file `data/players.json`? I would have to write some conditionals though wouldnt I. I am going to look into ajax with backbone.js hardcore though...

Comment: sorry but i misunderstood. I thought your json file was accessible via a URL. AFAIK there is no way to fetch a json file that's stored locally on the client's computer

Comment: mmm, ok well looks like I need to focus on a sever, but it's not a concern as of right now, I just need data stored locally, I just need to populate the local storage, this is a mobile app, and when installed wont have any data. Once the data is stored I am good to go and need to let the app know to stop accessing the collection via the hard coded version, and to work directly with local storage data.

Comment: That said I could look into storing the data on a server then fetching it with ajax, its not like the device wont have connection to the internet, so I may look into that if there isnt a really easy solution.

Comment: If you can fetch the data initially using `$.ajax()`, then you can simply initialize the collection manually with the fetched data. The local storage extension can then handle persistence

Comment: okay I have a rough idea how that would look, should the initalization come from maybe A. a timeout + confirmaiton to make sure it worked, or B. a manual click from a user to initialize the data. I dont mind a temp solution, whichever is the easiest for now. I need to look into how ajax works inside backbone, could you provide a small example, I can give you points if you can submit some kind of visual representation, I learn better that way.

Comment: Ok thats much better and actually makes sense :) Id love to try it, brb. Noob question but since backbone is such a modularized framework I am sure there is a specific place this piece should go.. not quite sure where to place this? Do I place it where my collection instance would normally be? Thanks for bearing with this question if you do lol.

Comment: Backbone doesn't enforce any particular application structure (unlike, say, Angular), so there isn't necessarily a particular way to organize your app. If this collection is the main data set for the application, I'd probably initialize it during app startup. Although it's just a little out of date by now, [Recipes with Backbone](http://recipeswithbackbone.com) might be a useful reference for you.